# Is it possible to add an organization to an existing GCP account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I am not being able to add an organization to an already exisiting GCP account.  The account has two projects running.  I created a different account in order to create an organization, because GCP would not let me add an organization in the same account.  After creating the account I get the following message:

[image: Google cloud platform saying the email account is not associated with an organization, and at the same time showing an organization available]

Answer (score 4):

When  you use only your personal account, the projects are attached to a virtual organization named "No Organisation".

If you have a domain name, you can create a [Cloud Identity account](https://admin.google.com) and an admin user. *Remove all licence on your user to pay nothing (even if you need to enroll for a free trial, do this and then remove the licences to pay nothing).*

So, now you have a new user (with @domainName), but you don't have your old project. No problem, go to the organisation level, in the IAM page and grand your personal account as Organisation Admin.

Go back in your personal account and you will be able to see your No Organization project and your new organization with the same account. Now, you simply need to [migrate project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) if you want to attach them to the new organization.

*Note: it's maybe lot of new stuff and step, but I did it and it worked well. Let me know if you need more guidance!*

Comment: Thank you so much, I felt so helpless trying to do this.  Will try it una few hours and post my results

Comment: I also had to give my personal account Project Creator to be able to migrate the project